# OG tags - Can i use fb:page_id instead of fb:app_id?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am about to add OG tags to all pages on our websites, but the documentation doesn't seem to mention anything about fb:page_id anymore. Is this depreciated? Or can I still use it in place of fb:app_id?

I notice that fb:profile_id is available, but I am trying to add tags that do not use a personal profile ID and would prefer to do it without the need to create App Ids for each site.

We do use Business Manager, so wondering if we could use the business ID if the above fails?

Any help on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, you cannot use the `page_id` anywhere in the web page. Even if you pass it in a OG meta tag, it will not render anywhere in facebook.com.